# XSLT remove duplicate nodes based on element value

Tags: xslt

I am newbie to XSLT.can you help me for xslt to achieve below output. In my input xml have duplicate nodes and i have to remove based on element (CustAccId) value should not be re-peat.

Inputxml :

```
        <Main>
 <Request>
    <TypeInd>I</TypeInd> 
    <CustAcctID>505665599</CustAcctID> 
     <ServiceOrderID>1452653</ServiceOrderID> 
  </Request>
  <Request>
  <TypeInd>O</TypeInd> 
  <CustAcctID>2011395</CustAcctID> 
   <ServiceOrderID>1452652</ServiceOrderID> 
       </Request>
     <Request>
    <TypeInd>I</TypeInd> 
   <CustAcctID>505665599</CustAcctID> 
    <ServiceOrderID>1452653</ServiceOrderID> 
       </Request>
       </Main>
```

Output XML :

```
 <Main>
      <Request>
         <TypeInd>I</TypeInd> 
         <CustAcctID>505665599</CustAcctID> 
        <ServiceOrderID>1452653</ServiceOrderID> 
   </Request>
 <Request>
       <TypeInd>O</TypeInd> 
       <CustAcctID>2011395</CustAcctID> 
         <ServiceOrderID>1452652</ServiceOrderID> 
  </Request>

Here is XSLt i tried but didn't work like it retrun duplicate request node

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:if test="not(following::Request[CustAcctID=current()])">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I suggest you start by reading about [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html); then search here for numerous examples previously posted.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the duplicate with following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Request[CustAcctID = following::Request/CustAcctID]"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
  <Request>
    <TypeInd>O</TypeInd> 
    <CustAcctID>2011395</CustAcctID> 
    <ServiceOrderID>1452652</ServiceOrderID> 
  </Request>
  <Request>
    <TypeInd>I</TypeInd> 
    <CustAcctID>505665599</CustAcctID> 
    <ServiceOrderID>1452653</ServiceOrderID> 
  </Request>
</Main>
```

The template matching all `Request` nodes where the `CustAcctID` matches the `CustAcctID` of the following `Request` will not produce any output for the matching `Request`, so the duplicates will not be written.

**Update** for the advice in the comment by michael.hor257k: Another approach is to use Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="x" match="ServiceOrderID" use="." />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="Request">
<xsl:for-each select=".">
  <xsl:if test="generate-id(ServiceOrderID) =
                generate-id(key('x', ServiceOrderID)[1])">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces the same output XML but can be more efficient as you'll find described in detail in the article by Jeni Tennison http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml that michael.hor257k already recommended.

As additional reference for XSLT grouping you can have a look at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for mentioning, already did that; as there is more than one way to get the desired result, I guess there are advantages using M. grouping instead of applying an empty template to filter out the duplicates, e.g. using M. grouping could be more efficient.

Comment: OTOH, your original solution is elegant (+1), and premature optimization rarely pays.

Comment: @kjhughes I don't think Muenchian grouping is "premature optimization" or optimization at all - it's simply a more efficient solution. As it bears no additional costs, it doesn't matter if it pays or not in the short term.

Comment: The procedurally biased Muenchian solution is superior where the performance improvement matters, but by forgoing the elegance of declarative pattern matching, it does indeed have a cost.