# Removing duplicate element from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some rather large xml files in which I need to remove specific duplicate elements, preferably with xslt.
I have tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789076/xslt-remove-duplicate-nodes-based-on-element-value) but without any luck.

The input xml may look like this

```
<workspace version="54">
<rootelement>
<description>Nice product</description>
<options>
<values>
.....
<values>
</options>
<product_structure>
<variable name="A">
<description>Feature A</description>
...
<language_translations>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
<language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
....
</language_translations>
...
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have one and only  per "/rootelement/product_structure/variable/language_translations".
Fortunately I am only operation with one language so the language attribute will always be "EN"

I am currently using XML Tools in Notepad++ to apply the xsl but if this can be done with any free command line tool I am willing to try that as well.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated! :)

Comment: Should there be only one `<language_translation>`element per `<language_translations>` element, or within a greater scope, or do you need to check the text for duplicates?

Comment: Do you simply want to remove any second, third etc. `language_translation` element? Or do you want to eliminate based on the element content?

Comment: Only one translation per translations, yes. But there will be many variable elements with translations and also other 'value' elements with the same structure of translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT will achieve what I currently believe you're asking. Please note the comments on your question so I can adjust this in case I'm mistaken.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="language_translations/language_translation[1]" priority="2">
         <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="language_translations/language_translation">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input XML (which I've modified a bit for completeness and readability)...

```
<workspace version="54">
    <rootelement>
        <description>Nice product</description>
        <options>
            <values>
.....
            </values>
        </options>
        <product_structure>
            <variable name="A">
                <description>Feature A</description>
...
                <language_translations>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>
....
                </language_translations>
            </variable>
        </product_structure>
    </rootelement>
</workspace>
```

It produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><workspace version="54">
    <rootelement>
        <description>Nice product</description>
        <options>
            <values>
.....
            </values>
        </options>
        <product_structure>
            <variable name="A">
                <description>Feature A</description>
...
                <language_translations>
                    <language_translation language="EN">Include big red button</language_translation>





....
                </language_translations>
            </variable>
        </product_structure>
    </rootelement>
</workspace>
```

If needed I can also provide a version that takes the `language` attribute into account (removing only duplicate languages).

The XSLT will by default copy anything from the input. If it encounters a `language_translation` element within `language_translations`, it invokes the empty template at the end, resulting in no output. However, for the **first** `language_translation` within a `language_translations`, the template above takes precedence (notice the priority). So only that one gets copied.

Comment: With processor are you using to apply the stylesheet, I can't seem to get it working using the XML Tools plugin in Notepad++ :(

Comment: @bwedel I've tried it in http://xslttest.appspot.com/. It's an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet so pretty much any correct processor should be able to handle it correctly. Do you get an error or incorrect output?

Comment: No error at all, but it will try to combine Kim's suggestion with yours and see if it works :)

Comment: Got it working, and added <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> to clean up the blank lines. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you have a `<language_translation language="EN">Include big green button</language_translation>` among your translations? Still your desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

So as I get your question, you want to eliminate the 2nd, 3rd etc. `<language_translation>` containing the same text within the same `<language_translations>`. My approach would be to write a template that does nothing if there exists a preceding sibling with the same text value:

```
<xsl:template match="language_translation[text()=preceding-sibling::language_translation/text()]"/>
```

Comment: Apparently the text doesn't matter. If I'm misinterpreting bwedel's comment on his/her question, your template can replace the last two in my stylesheet.

Comment: I'm still not sure what bwedel really wants. He says he wants to ignore the `language` attribute. But does he want to ignore the text, too?

Comment: I think so, yes. If I'm interpreting literally what he says, then it means one `language_translation` element per parent (not necessarily a `language_translations` element; note the plural). But it could be interpreted as meaning "remove the duplicate texts".